# Priorize DNS records by server locatoion

Tags: linux, networking, hosts-file

Recently I had assigned a task where I am suposed to optimize the login time for a Redhat SSO service that is installed on a RHEL 7.9.
This service uses multiple Active directories to validate the user's credentials. All these AD's are spread around Europe.
I would like to setup some of the AD's that i already know that are near my server to be queried first, but I also want to be able to query other ones in case if those that are closer are down. Could you help me with a solution? The most obvious one would be to add the prefered ones inside the /etc/hosts file, but this will make it impossible to reach the other ones...

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about *by location*, but *by address* should be possible using `gai.conf`, assuming the application you are looking at is doing normal lookups using `getaddrinfo` and that it's acceptable that this prioritization affects all lookups by applications running on that same machine.

If we have for instance these records in DNS:

```
test.example.com.             3600    IN      AAAA    2001:db8:1::1
test.example.com.             3600    IN      AAAA    2001:db8:ffff::1
test.example.com.             3600    IN      A       192.0.2.1
test.example.com.             3600    IN      A       198.51.100.1
```

And test the `getaddrinfo` behavior using `getent ahosts`, you get something like this with the default configuration:

```
$ getent ahosts test.example.com
2001:db8:1::1   STREAM test.example.com
2001:db8:1::1   DGRAM
2001:db8:1::1   RAW
2001:db8:ffff::1 STREAM
2001:db8:ffff::1 DGRAM
2001:db8:ffff::1 RAW
192.0.2.1       STREAM
192.0.2.1       DGRAM
192.0.2.1       RAW
198.51.100.1    STREAM
198.51.100.1    DGRAM
198.51.100.1    RAW
$
```

(With the records jumping around randomly among the v6 and v4 alternatives respectively if you run the command multiple times.)

If we say that your favorite addresses are `2001:db8:ffff::1` and `198.51.100.1` (based on being closer, more reliable, or whatever) you could put something like this in `gai.conf`:

```
precedence ::ffff:198.51.100.1/128  99
precedence 2001:db8:ffff::1/128 100
```

And to not remove the default behavior also include:

```
precedence  ::1/128       50
precedence  ::/0          40
precedence  2002::/16     30
precedence ::/96          20
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  10
```

Then you would get:

```
$ getent ahosts test.example.com
2001:db8:ffff::1 STREAM test.example.com
2001:db8:ffff::1 DGRAM
2001:db8:ffff::1 RAW
198.51.100.1    STREAM
198.51.100.1    DGRAM
198.51.100.1    RAW
2001:db8:1::1   STREAM
2001:db8:1::1   DGRAM
2001:db8:1::1   RAW
192.0.2.1       STREAM
192.0.2.1       DGRAM
192.0.2.1       RAW
$
```